# what is the replacement of getJdbcTemplate() in spring.jdbc 4.2.5 i m using spring-4.2.5,spring-jdbc.4.2.5.mvn3

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

```
@Override
    public Page<KeyClient> getKeyClients(KeyClient searchClient,
            List<Integer> selectedClients, boolean isExclude, int pageNo, int pageSize) throws DataAccessException {
        StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer(GET_CLIENT_LIST);
        StringBuffer query1 = new StringBuffer(GET_CLIENT_LIST_COUNT);


        /*StringBuffer query2 = new StringBuffer(GET_CLIENT_LIST1);
        StringBuffer query3 = new StringBuffer(GET_CLIENT_LIST_COUNT1);*/



        /*Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params = buildQueryForClients(searchClient, selectedClients, isExclude, query);*/


                Object[] params = buildQueryForClients(searchClient, selectedClients, isExclude, query, query1);

                PaginationHelper<KeyClient> ph = new PaginationHelper<KeyClient>();
                return ph.fetchPage(getJdbcTemplate(), query1.toString(),
                        query.toString(), params, pageNo, pageSize,
                new SingleColumnRowMapper<KeyClient>(){}.
```

there is error in the return statement getJdbcTemplate() error is- The method getJdbcTemplate() is undefined for the type MedNeXtCommonDAOImpl.

Answer (score 0):

See [4.2.5 docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE) Class `JdbcDaoSupport` method `getJdbcTemplate()`:

> public final JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() Return the
>   JdbcTemplate for this DAO, pre-initialized with the DataSource or set
>   explicitly.